# Windows 7 back up DVD's

Tags: windows-7, installation, backup, operating-systems, dvd

I have a laptop running on windows 7 home basic.
It got infected with viruses and i'd like to re-install windows 7.
When i bought this laptop 4 years ago,i did not know much about computers and
I made 3 DVD's of the Operating System as prompted by the system.
The problem is,i don't know what they are and what they do.Are they just back up files ? or a system image?

These are the questions i have in my mind:

1. Can i use those DVD's to re-install windows 7?
2. If so,will it return to the condition in which i bought it?
3. Also i've never seen an OS occupy 3 DVD's.So is it really an OS?

Thank you

Comment: I believe the answer to all 3 of your questions is yes ...

Comment: Yes to all three. The last, to expand, will be the manufacturer's personalised image of Windows (extra software, drivers and settings). A normal Windows 7 dial contains a (roughly) 4GB WIM of the bare OS. As yours spans 3 DVDs then I would say that they've installed extras and then taken a WIM of their customisations.

Comment: @BigChris Thank you for the elaborate explanation.